# map values from database to viewmodels

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the values from database list to the ViewModels' local variable in controller. I wanted to use GetValue method to do so but it doesn't exist in this context and I have no idea why.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MySQL msql = new MySQL();                          
        List<string> results = msql.SelectList("Select * from table");
        var model = new List<MyViewModels>(results.Count);    

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
            model.Add(new MyViewModels() {
                //this is want I want to do but GetValue method doesn't exist
                bID = results[i].GetValue("bID");
                status = results[i].GetValue("status")                   
            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because results is a `List<string>` you are effectively trying to call `"".GetValue("bID")` which is not possible. Strings have no `GetValue` function.

This also does not make any sense

```
List<string> results = msql.SelectList("Select * from table");
```

This will ONLY work if the table only has one column.